# MongoDB converting date to string

Tags: mongodb

**PROBLEM:**

Error when get `Y-m-d` from `"SentTimestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-23T22:20:15Z")`

**DETAILS :**

**document :**

```
{
...
"SentTimestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-23T22:20:15Z")
...
}
```

**query :**

```
db.foo.find({}, {$dateToString: {format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$SentTimestamp"}})
```

**Error :**

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1 field in obj: { format: \"%Y-%m-%d\", date: \"$SentTimestamp\" }",
    "code" : 17287
```

Can somebody explain how can I convert date to string, what is wrong above ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use the [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator with projection in the [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method. Instead, use it with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) in the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline phase to return documents that have the datetime field converted to string with the desired format, as in the following example:

Using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/):

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "sentDateString": { 
            "$dateToString": { 
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                "date": "$SentTimestamp" 
            } 
        }
    } }
])
```

or using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "sentDateString": { 
            "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                    "date": "$SentTimestamp" 
            } 
        },
        "otherFields": 1, ....
    } }
])
```

Comment: @chridam - can we have mix of find and aggregate.. i have to use find query as well.. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can include queries with your aggregate operation by using the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline step. Read more with examples [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match).

Comment: Is it there a chance to do this without `$project`? Because I don't want to project all the fields from an entry..they are about 40 which is a lot.

Comment: @Tenzolinho You can use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) like in the above edit