# How to extract only Day Month and Hour from mongoDB Timestamp string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a result from the MongoDB database which includes timestamps in the format shown below[image]

I would like to have it displayed in this format: Thurs 12th, 2019 or 28/12/2019

In my model, I am extracting the modifiedBy from ;

```
{timestamps:true}
```

How do I make this conversion?

Comment: Hey you can use [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) to do this.

Comment: I know, but I just can't get it right, could you show a sample code snippet that can guide me ?

Comment: I have added a little snippet in an answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: Aggregation has a `$dateToString` operator, which can be used to format date as "28/12/2019". Here is post with an answer: [mongodb-converting-date-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856038/mongodb-converting-date-to-string).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of achieving this through [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
var date = moment('2019-11-28T05:38:47.089Z');
console.log(date.format("ddd Mo YYYY"))
```